# Find partition function for a classical harmonic oscillator with time harmonic forcing

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, partition-function

I have been trying to find partition function for classical harmonic oscillator with time harmonic forcing term and reached an expression. I want to know if I am correct.

There is abundant literature for partition function of classical harmonic oscillator.

We know that it is $\frac{2\pi}{h\beta\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}}$

Now, if I add a forcing term like to the Harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian, such that $H(x, p)=p^{2} / 2 m+m \omega_{0}^{2} x^{2} / 2-f(t) x$

where $f(t)=f_o$, for start let us consider constant forcing

the partition function is
$Z=\frac{1}{h} \int e^{-\beta H(x, p)} d x d p=\frac{2 \pi}{h \beta \omega_{0}} \exp \left(\frac{\beta f_{0}^{2}}{2 m \omega_{0}^{2}}\right)$

now if I change the forcing to
$f(t)=f_o\cos(\omega t)$

Can the partition function be written as 
$\frac{2 \pi}{h \beta \omega_{0}} \exp \left(\frac{\beta f_{0}^{2}\cos(\omega t)^2}{2 m \omega_{0}^{2}}\right)$

It contains extra $\cos(\omega t)^2$ term. I can't see if I am going wrong somewhere.

Comment: A system subject to external forcing is not in thermodynamic equilibrium. Consequently it does not really make sense to talk about it having a partition function at all. The only way I can see to make sense of the expression you have derived is in the limit $\omega$ much less than the relaxation time of the system, or to put it another way, in the limit where the applied force varies so slowly that it can be seen as a fixed parameter and does not apply any forcing.

Comment: @By Symmetry Thanks, I have hardly read, non-equilibrium statistical mechanics. If partition function doesn't help, can you point to some article to let me know how, the fluctuations are found in non-equilibrium statistical mechanics. For example, in this system, finding fluctuations in position.